# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError - couldn't find DSO to load

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, crashlytics

In my React Native application, this log keeps appearing in Crashlytics. I have tried the current solutions, but I couldn't get any results. How can I solve this problem?

The solutions I have tried:

android/app/build.gradle

```java
android {
    packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libfbjni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libfbjni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libfbjni.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libfbjni.so'
    pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
    }
}

dependencies:{
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
implementation "org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+"
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the
[screenshot of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqV17.png).